# .map multiple entries from DB Query

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to work out if you can have multiple "map objects" in the .set?

For example I have employees... I need one array per employee, or multiple map "key" objects maybe?

So maybe I need something like Map(0).get('UserID')
Map(1).get('UserID')

etc?

```
var map = new Map();

while not rs.eof

    map.set('UniqueID', i)
    .set('UserID', UserID)
    .set('FullURL', URL)
    .set('Age', 39)
    .set('XXXX', XXX)

rs.movenext
wend
```

What I am looking to do is have multiple map objects i.e. 1 = UniqueID 1, 2 = UniqueID = 2.

Right now it brings back the last record.

Comment: Is there any reason you're choosing a Map over an Object here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value against same variable again and again that's why in the end map shows you the last value. If you want to save an object against every unique value you can do it like that. You can use array if you want to instead of object. I hope this will solve your query.

**Map overwrite the existing value that's what you are doing**

```
var map1 = new Map();
var object={
UserID: 'UserID',
FullURL :'URL'};

map1.set('id', object);
map1.set('id', "2");

console.log(map1.get('id'))
```

**Solution**

```
var map = new Map();
var object  = {};

while not rs.eof
    object = {
UserID : UserID,
FullURL : URL
}
    map.set(i, object )

rs.movenext
wend
```